# Orchard CMS 1.7 Orchard.OutputCache Module form redirects adds querystring, i have code for querystring suppression, but any down sides?

Tags: module, content-management-system, orchardcms, outputcache, orchardcms-1.7

Regarding the Orchard 1.7 `Orchard.OutputCache` (version listed below). We have SEO releated need to suppress the querystring from being appended on a form redirect to a simple "thank you" page.  The Cache module wants to append a QS  but not sure why.

See line 452 in `Orchard.OutputCache.Filters`

```
var querystring = "?" + string.Join("&", Array.ConvertAll(qs.AllKeys, k => string.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(k), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(qs[k]))));
```

What I have done seems too simple a fix, and I fear I am missing some landmine.

I have simply changed the code a bit to add a condition -

I get the `ignored` and check it against the `redirecturl` that was retrieved in line 421.  So now instead of always running the line above, if the redirect URL is declared in ignore list, no `querystring` appended - good for SEO team. 
These "thank you" pages are basic CMS content so are not effected by the form entry.

My question is - But what are the down sides if any?

Below is updated code around line 452 in `Orchard.OutputCache.Filters`
of

--- module.txt--

```
Name: Output Cache
AntiForgery: enabled
Author: Sébastien Ros
Website: http://orchardproject.net/
Version: 1.7.2
OrchardVersion: 1.7.2
```

---

code was changed from simply...

```
   var querystring = "?" + string.Join("&", Array.ConvertAll(qs.AllKeys, k => string.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(k), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(qs[k]))));
```

to...

```
  var querystring = "";

  _ignoredUrls = _cacheManager.Get("CacheSettingsPart.IgnoredUrls",
   context =>
   {
      context.Monitor(_signals.When(CacheSettingsPart.CacheKey));
      return _workContext.CurrentSite.As<CacheSettingsPart>().IgnoredUrls;
   }
  );

  if (!IsIgnoredUrl(redirectUrl, _ignoredUrls))
  {
     querystring = "?" + string.Join("&", Array.ConvertAll(qs.AllKeys, k => string.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(k), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(qs[k]))));
  }
```

We have many sites (dozens) that will need this update, and this seems to work fine, My question is - But what are the down sides if any?  Might anyone know why that querystring is append on a form submission redirect in the first place?

I'd rather not want to find bad news after releasing this update all around.

Any comments at all are very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

toma

Updated issue from our SEO team:

When a given "Thank you" page is reached, it indicates a "goal" has been completed, as set within Google Analytics - (a conversion).
The user did not just start the form, they completed the form, and were taken to that forms "thank you" page.

With the Query strings attached, the SEO team cannot properly track conversions based on a thank you page URL - as it is unique each time a user visits it.

( http://localhost:3026/request-a-part-thank-you?__r=8d1ff290a58bb80 )

...

I know it's kind of weird  - the "thank you" pages could and should actually be cached, but I saw a quick and easy code update to use the ignore url to prevent it from getting the query string on the redirect - solving their issue quickly.  Like most shops, there is always something else to get on with, and everyone is always in a hurry.

Comment: Can you explain what the SEO concern is exactly?

Comment: Thanks Bertrand - im truly honored to receive your help.

Comment: That doesn't sound convincing: a search engine will never submit those forms and thus will never see the querystring. This doesn't sound like an issue at all.

Comment: I have updated the bottom part of the question area - see just below "Updated issue from our SEO team:" ...

Comment: I see. You should file a bug.

Comment: Will do - thanks.   But no comment on proposed quick fix to remove query string?   Would anyone know why the query string is appended on a redirect in the first place ?

Comment: It's added to prevent a cached response from being returned. I don't see any "quick fix" because this is a tricky issue. I wouldn't touch that without discussing it with Sébastien.